# Passing a predicate to QWaitCondition?

Tags: c++, qt, mutex, condition-variable

I'm writing some threads in Qt and I can't figure out how to pass a predicate to my condition variable to protect against spurious wake up.

Working solution in C++:

```
std::mutex(mu);
std::condition_variable cond;

std::unique_lock<mutex> alpha_lock(mu);
cond.wait(alpha_lock, [](){ return //some condition;});
alpha_lock.unlock();

//Continue to do stuff...
```

Qt equivalent:

```
QMutex mu;
QWaitCondition cond;

QMutexLocker alpha_lock&(mu);
cond.wait(&mu, [](){return //some condition;})
```

Error:

```
"no matching member function for call to wait"
```

Any ideas on how to use a predicate in this Qt code?

Comment: Where do ou see any documentation that you can pass a callback to QaitCondition?   I'm not seeing anything.    http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwaitcondition.html   I'm guessing you just wrap it in a while loop.  while (!condition_to_test) qtwaitcondition.wait();

Comment: The real question is: Since you have a working solution using standard C++, why are you limiting yourself by transcoding it to use Qt? Is there a reason you cannot use your working C++ solution?

Comment: @IInspectable this is for a desktop app, hence using Qt contracts to ensure fully cross platform compatible

Comment: Qt is certainly no more portable than standard C++. If anything, it's the other way around. Using standard C++ ensures, that you can compile your program for any platform, for which there is a conforming C++ compiler.

Comment: @IInspectable one difference would be that Qt's threading classes are also available for compilers that are not C++11 capable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler and @xaxxon have already pointed out, there is no such `wait()` overload in `QWaitCondition`.

If you want to check a condition before going on you can do it like this

```
while (!condition()) {
    cond.wait(mutex);
}
```

You can of course put that into a helper function that takes a `QWaitCondition`, `QMutex` and `std::function` if you need this in more places. Or derive from `QWaitCondition` adding the overload doing the loop above.