# How to get resizeEvent-already-executed?

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have a QDialog-inherited class and **one of its sub-window is initialized on resizeEvent** like this.

```
void OpenGLWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) {

    QWindow::resizeEvent(event);

    // initialize on  first call
    if (m_context == nullptr)
        initOpenGL();

    resizeGL(width(), height());
}
```

Because OpenGL init needs width and height information, and need to adapt window size change, this init code can't move other place.

I should open this dialog and initialize some OpenGL draw objects.

```
m_Dialog->show();
m_Dialog->init(init_paramter); //I have to create opengl buffers of draw objects here
```

But unfortunately, **resizeEvent() is called after init method was invoked**.

e.g. current execution order is as following.

```
my_dialog_open_function() {
      m_Dialog->show();
      m_Dialog->init(init_paramter);
}
void OpenGLWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)
```

As OpenGL system was not initialized by resizeEvent Handler, my **m_Dialog->init invoke crashes**.

How can I get this execution flow?

```
m_Dialog->show();
void OpenGLWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent * event)
m_Dialog->init(init_paramter);
```

Where is the proper place I can invoke my init function safely?

Comment: From the code it looks like `initOpenGL();` (I assume it assigns something to `m_context`) does not need width and height. Only the call to `resizeGL(width(), height());`. Unless init method is more complex and it has some dependency to window geometry.

Comment: ah, thanks. I'll try to move (if (m_context == nullptr) initOpenGL();) to global init area.

Comment: @pptaszni, I put initOpenGL in constructor, and crashed directly. It seems that initOpenGL should be called in any callback(like resizeEvent) where widget is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @pptaszni mentioned in his comment, `initOpenGL()` doesn't look like it needs size information. So first I would reconsider the design.

As for the question:
The resize event is scheduled after the show and delivered when GUI events are processed. That's after your function returns.

You can simply delay the call by posting some event, which then will be delivered after the resize event. The easiest way is to use a single shot timer:

```
m_Dialog->show();

// Call me in 1ms
QTimer::singleShot(1, [=]() {
   m_Dialog->init(init_paramter);
});
```

Note the delay of 1ms. If you call it with 0, Qt will optimize and call the handler immediately, so no gain there.

Comment: Thank, king_nak, using your timer, Can I get flow (show, resizeEvent, init) in 100%?  Or 99% working and 1% (show, init, resizeEvent)? If it's not 100%, it can result hidden bug. But if you have real experience in real project this way, I'll use it in my project.

Comment: I tried with 1ms, 100ms, and when I give 1ms, I get (show, init, crash). when I give 100ms, I get (show, resizeEvent, init). so do you think If I give enough time, then I can get 100% success? It's pity I can't show you video screenshot

Comment: To be sure you would need to do sth like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40450855/4165552) and call your `init` after the condition (`resizeEvent` called) is satisfied. But this is the direct solution to your question, which does not look like the best solution to your problem. I would rather investigate what are the exact preconditions for this openGL window setup, unfortunately I am not the expert.

Comment: I did use this setup in real projects (that is, postponing a call after events of a previous call were handled). However, never with a resize-event directly after `show`... It seems that the resize is not directly triggered by the show as I assumed, so it might not be the optimal solution :/ One way would be to increase the timeout (dirty), or use a condition variable like @pptaszni suggestet (dirty-ish). Best would be to not rely on the resize for one-time init of the GL. That reminds me: could you do it in the show-event?

Comment: with 100ms, I am happy. thank you. so far, i didn't experience any crash.